# display mysql data in a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to us php to pick up information from my mysql (phphmyadmin) database and display it with checkboxes, when I run my code I can display the radio button but no text seems to display from the database. Any ideas why this is ?

Here is my code, I linked to my database in another file which I have linked in my code but that is not shown here.

```
<?php 
        $query1 = "SELECT town FROM place WHERE ID = 1";        
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die("Invalid Query");

        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){

             $town = $row1["town"];
             echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"town\" value=\"$town\" />$town";     
       }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting the value of $town?

Comment: @Rebekh put your table with sample values.

Comment: like I said nothing appears next to the checkbox

Comment: Which field of your town table you want to show here ?

Comment: the town which is set to $row1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you use the function **mysqli_fetch_assoc** instead of **mysqli_fetch_row** because then you have the array ready as you use it. With mysqli_fetch_row the result array is only indexed with ascending index - no names.

`while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){ 
...`

instead of

`while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)){
...`

Note: Consider Using PDO

Comment: You can use mysqli just fine, but not mysql.

Comment: *"Note: You shouldn't use the mysqli-interface at all, use PDO."* - Oh, why so?

Comment: Ok "mysqli_" is ok, but never "mysql_" but if you learn php anyway in my opinion its better to work with PDO because of prepared statements, flexibility...